# I want to open pop up after 30 seconds using jquery.I have used addClass() with fade in

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have update this code.When site load if works perfect but when I work on another page without wait 30 seconds it also opens pop up but not mast.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 setTimeout(function() {
 if(sessionStorage["dialogshow"] != 'yes'){  
    
 //var url = window.location.pathname;
 

 // if(url == '/test/')
 //{ 
       
        //$("#dataCapture").fadeIn(3000); 
  $("#dataCapture").addClass("fade in"); 
  $('#dataCapture').css('display', 'block');
   $('#dataCapture').attr("aria-hidden","false");
    
 
   // Add the mask to body
    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    $('#mask').fadeIn(300);
 sessionStorage["dialogshow"] = 'yes';
 
        return false;
 
 //}
}
},10000);
});
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
if (sessionStorage["dialogshow"] != 'yes') {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    if (url == '/test/') {
      $("#dataCapture").addClass("fade in");
      $('#dataCapture').css('display', 'block');
      $('#dataCapture').attr("aria-hidden", "false");
      // Add the mask to body
      $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
      $('#mask').fadeIn(300);
      sessionStorage["dialogshow"] = 'yes';
      return false;
    }
  }, 30000);
}
```

Comment: the problem with your code is after 30 sec the condition has been checked and if suppose developer want to do something in if block the code has to wait for 30 sec . btw u r correct but small changes you have to do.

Comment: @Rahul thanks for the suggestion. I have made that update.

Comment: @Rino Raj you most welcome. we are here to give suggestions only

Answer (score 0):

you can use setTimeout method of javascript.

i.e whenever your page is load in browser you have to use setTimeout method of jquery for loading.

see the example

```
if (url == '/test/') {

  // add your logic here in setTimeout to load the popup after 30 sec
  setTimeout(function(){ 
  $("#dataCapture").addClass("fade in");
  $('#dataCapture').css('display', 'block');
  $('#dataCapture').attr("aria-hidden", "false");

  }, 30000);


  // Add the mask to body
  $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
  $('#mask').fadeIn(300);
  sessionStorage["dialogshow"] = 'yes';
  return false;
}
```

Comment: pop up is not opening

Comment: It also not open at first time

Comment: Only first code is working.But if i am doing something on another page after site load without waiting 30 seconds,the pop up is not open

Comment: there might be problem with your code. because if you used it properly it should work. check your code and then correct it and then run it or make available it here we will check where is problem.

Comment: you are navigating to other page  like if page A is loading  in page the code is working ok. and when you navigate the page to Page B it is not working Right ?

Comment: Yess. On my home page it is working.In my other pages pop is open but black mask is not open

Comment: on other page you have added this JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
     if (sessionStorage["dialogshow"] != 'yes') {

       //var url = window.location.pathname;


       // if(url == '/test/')
       //{ 

       //$("#dataCapture").fadeIn(3000); 
       $("#dataCapture").addClass("fade in");
       $('#dataCapture').css('display', 'block');
       $('#dataCapture').attr("aria-hidden", "false");


       // Add the mask to body
       $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
       $('#mask').fadeIn(300);
       sessionStorage["dialogshow"] = 'yes';

       return false;

       //}
     }
   }, 10000);
 });
```

Comment: According to this code it will check for 10 second, but in your question it is posted as 30 sec. and as far as your answer is concerned the problem with your code is after 30 sec the condition has been checked and if suppose developer want to do something in if block the code has to wait for 30 sec . I think that is bad way of coding :)

Comment: Ya i know that.I want 30 sec.But for checking speedy i just add 10 sec

Answer (score 0):

You cannot animate the `display` attribute with css transitions.

You should use `visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;` then `visibility: visible; opacity: 1;` instead of `display: none` then `display: block;`